# PHP File upload not working on FF browser - throwing "The connection was reset" error

Tags: php, html

Starting new thread here for the issue.

Hi everyone.
I am having the problem in PHP file upload [a simple text file having string "hello world"]. 
Its works fine with other browser like Google Chrome, IE, etc.

But having problem in FF browser. getting "The connection was reset" error.
Anyone knows whats happening here? any help would be appreciated.
Here is the usecase -

I.e - I have a page say page1.php - in this page I am having a simple html file upload tag - 
Page1.php

```
<html>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="testF" id="testF"
    action="upload.php" method="post">Enter file:<input
    type="file" name="tfile" id="tfile" /> <input type="submit" name="sub"
    id="sub" value="Upload" /></form>
</body>
</html>
```

upload.php - 
I this file I am just printing the $_FILE array.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
    echo("Sub clicked, got in!");
    echo("<pre>");
    print_r($_FILES);
}
else
{
    echo "File is not uploaded";
}
?>
```

Update - 
This works absolutely fine on development environment [Local machine]. Issue is on production server.

Comment: @jonijones Can you please tell what went wrong in this form? thnx.

Comment: I don't think the issue is in your form, I think it is in your PHP configuration on your production server.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I don't think so.. Its working like a charm on other browser say Google Chrome, IE!.  If this is production server configuration issue than can you please guide me bit more here. what conf setting should I look for ?

Comment: You said that FF works on  your development server. So there must be a difference between the servers. You can start by comparing the PHP.ini's of each server.

Comment: @Mr.coder - Using Win XP and Ubuntu for development purpose [Test server]

Comment: How large ist your file and your `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size` in php.ini?

Comment: upload_max_filesize is 2m, post_max_size is 8m and the file that I am uploading is just 4 - 8 KB.

Comment: Do you have a ssl cert on production?

Comment: No, i have also tried testing from other 2 servers. but same result !